# Excel vlookup table array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vlookup

Please forgive me if the formula isn´t correctly translated as my Excel is in Spanish.

=IF.ERROR(VLOOKUP(B3;[**17.01.2017**.xlsx]Hoja1!$A$2:$B$29;2;FALSE);"")

What I need is to get the date from the active workbook where the formula is and have the rest remain the same where its getting the infomration from a different workbook.

Woorkbook1:

[image]

Workbook2:

[image]

The formula is where you can see **21.481,65**. This formula is getting this information from another workbook named **17.01.2017.xlsx**.

I want the date to be the same as the date seen in the image on the left.

Comment: Get the date from where in the active workbook? Can you add an example of your data in both workbooks, and the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT to reference a different sheet.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B$3, INDIRECT("'[" & $A4 & ".xlsx]" & "Hoja1'!$A$2:$B$29" ), 2, FALSE), "")
```

This is the same as your formula, but instead of `[17.01.2017.xlsx]Hoja1!$A$2:$B$29` it is replaced with `INDIRECT("'[" & $A4 & ".xlsx]" & "Hoja1'!$A$2:$B$29" )`.

You might have to change the formatting to fit with the Spanish Excel, and also make sure the file extension is correct `.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm` etc.

This will only work if all files are open, also I don't think you can save a file with `/` so your dates would have to be with a `.` instead.